# Symfony2 Doctrine Raw SQL Stored Procedure Loop through multiple result sets

Tags: symfony, stored-procedures, doctrine-orm

I have managed to execute raw SQL (ie no ResultSetMapping) and can call and execute an MSSQL Stored Procedure.

The code I have is as follows:

```
$em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();
$stmt = $em
    ->getConnection()
    ->prepare('EXEC someSP :id,null,:uid');
$stmt->bindValue('id', '629674');
$stmt->bindValue('uid', '217');
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

No that works fine; however the issue i have is if the SP returns more than one result set the above only returns the first result set. Is there any way to loop through and get each result set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I was able to do this but i had to create my own wrapper around the connection:

Its a work around at best but the code basically creates a new PDO connection using the DBAL params in conf.yml. it them prepares and executes the statement and returns all the result sets.

code is free to use here:
https://github.com/scott-davidjones/Symfony2DBALSPWrapper

Answer (score 1):

I had to deal with the similar issue and this is what I came up with. This function is from the class that extends Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository so I have access to the _em property in general case you can use `$this->get('doctrine')->getManager();` to get entity manager.

```
protected function execMultiSetQuery($query, $params, $connection = 'default') {
    // Init
    $conn = $this->_em
        ->getConnection($connection)
        ->getWrappedConnection();

    // Processing
    if ($conn instanceof \Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection) {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute($params);

        // Loop through the row sets
        $results = array();
        do {
            try {
                $results[] = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            }
            catch (\Exception $e) {}
        } while($stmt->nextRowset());

        $stmt->closeCursor(); // Clean up
        return $results;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try and itterate over each set 1 by one. But really fetchAll should do the same as below, cant hurt to try though...

```
$em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();
$stmt = $em
    ->getConnection()
    ->prepare('EXEC someSP :id,null,:uid');
$stmt->bindValue('id', '629674');
$stmt->bindValue('uid', '217');
$stmt->execute();
do{
    $results[] = $stmt->fetchAll()
} while($stmt->nextRowset());
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, i tried that but no luck :( begining to think it might be the way the pdo_sqlsrv driver from MS works.. you kinda have to do ```sqlsrv_next_result``` in order to move to the next result set, but not sure how to do this in symfony2/doctrine2

Comment: You couldnt just do it from within the code similar to what i have changed my answer to be above using your code from your wrapper?

Comment: unfortunatly not as the nextRowset() does not exist in Doctrine.. or atleast i could not get it to work..